# is it possible to use the .java extension files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

can I call the java extension files in the Xcode?.i.e Can I create the Object for that class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1  This needs ALOT more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode *used to* have some support for Java (e.g. you could have java projects).

now, you would have to setup custom build phases for your Java sources. so, it could function as a tool, but i think most of the functionality has been pulled by now - you'd actually have better luck using older versions of Xcode, which included project and target templates for Java stuffs.

on osx, Idea or Eclipse (or others) is better suited for Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible as far as my knowledge